# Convergence of sequence and serie

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\}\subset (0, +\infty)$ a sequence such that $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n < \infty$. Define:
$$\rho_1= \frac{1}{1 + a_1} \ \ and \ \ \rho_{n + 1} = \frac{\rho_n}{1 + a_n} $$
Show that $\rho_n = \prod_{k = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{1 + a_k}$ and $\rho_n$ is monotone and decreasing, bounded and $\rho = \lim \rho_n > 0$.
The first part is easy, my trouble is about the convergence of $\rho$, I'm trying with this:
$$ \rho_n = \frac{1}{1 + a_1}\times\frac{1}{1+a_2}\times \cdots \times \frac{1}{1 + a_n} $$
$$ln(\rho_n) = -[ln(1 + a_1) + ln(1 + a_2) + \cdots +ln(1 + a_n)] $$
Finally:
$$ln(\rho_n) < -ln(a_1 a_2\cdots a_n) $$

Comment: Do you know that $\ln (1+x) \le x$?

Answer (score 1):

The sequence ${\rho_{n}}$ is bounded below by 0 and above by 1. Also $\rho_{n}$ is monotone decreasing. therefore $\rho_{n}$ converges to some limit $\rho$ as a consequence of the monotone convergence theorem for sequences. You aren't asked to find $\rho$ so you are done.

So you also want to show $\rho$ is not zero.

As you have done take the natural log:

$ln(\prod \frac{1}{1+a_{n}}) = - \sum ln(1+a_{n}) $

For all finite sums.

Looking at a series expansion of ln(1+x) around zero you can obtain bounds that you can use to bound your series.

So expanding as a series about x=0 we have $$ln(1+x)= x - \frac{x^{2}}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} + ...$$

So near zero $ln(1+x) < x$ and a tail of $a_{n}$ will be arbitrarily close to 0 eventually. So $\sum ln(1+a_{n}) < \sum a_{n}$ where here the sum is taken over a tail of the sequence.

So $ln(\prod \frac{1}{1+a_{n}}) > -M$ for some M since the sum of $a_{n}$ is less than infinity. So $\rho > e^{-M}$.

Comment: It still remains to show that the limit $\rho$ is strictly positive.

Comment: For this, I should use $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n < +\infty$